# Repeater Media-Tech MT4218 cannot be configured because of allegedly invalid password

Tags: wireless-router, repeater

I am trying to set up the MT4218 router/repeater to work in the `Repeater` mode.

Every time I enter the password, the following error message is shown:

> Pass Phrase is invalid

I am sure the password is correct.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration panel uses the following function to check if the entered string is safe in terms of a potential SQL injection attack:

```
var checkInjection = function(str)
{
    var len = str.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == ';' || str.charAt(i) == ',' ||
                str.charAt(i) == '\r' || str.charAt(i) == '\n') {
            return false;
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
    return true;
};
```

It means that passwords that contain a semi-colon or a comma (or the whitespace characters `\r` or `\n`) are considered invalid, even if they are in fact correct and perfectly innocuous.